# Intuitive reason why minimization is harder in multiple dimensions for separable functions

Tags: algorithm, optimization, time-complexity, computation-theory, minimization

Let's say I have N positive-valued 1-d functions. Does it take more function evaluations for a numerical minimizer to minimize their product in N-dimensional space rather than do N individual 1d minimizations?

If so, is there an intuitive way to understand this? Somehow I feel like both problems should be equal in complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Minimizing their product is minimizing the sum of their logs. There are many algorithms for min(max)imizing N-dimensional functions. One is the old standby OPTIF9.
If you have to use hard limits, so you're minimizing in a box, that can be a lot harder, but you can usually avoid it.

Comment: But is it faster to do the problem in N-d rather than do N separate 1-d minimizations? And if so why?

Comment: @Alex, if the problem is separable, then sure. In general, you do N-dimensional optimization if the dimensions are interrelated. If the solution for each dimension *i* depends on the solutions for some or all the other dimensions. For example, in my work in pharmacometrics, if you've got a bunch of blood samples taken over time after a dose, you need to estimate both blood volume and renal elimination rate. These two dimensions are inter-related. You can't estimate them independently.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is not linear in the number of variables. Typically `n` small problems is better than one big problem. Or in other words: making the problem twice as big (in terms of variables) will make it more than twice as expensive to solve.

In some special cases it may be somewhat beneficial to batch a few problems, mainly due to fixed overhead (some solvers do a lot of things before actually starting iterating).

Comment: What drives this nonlinear scaling, particularly in the case of a separable function?

Comment: Solvers do not know the problem is separable, so they just look at it as a big N dimensional problem. None of the algorithms I know have linear complexity. A simple example is just solving `Ax=b`: this is `O(n^3)`.

Comment: My gut feeling was that somehow taking a single step along the N-d gradient will get you to the same place as taking the N 1-d steps that you would when minimizing the individual functions (IF the N-d function is the product of N 1d functions).